# Button for Collapsing a Bootstrap SideBar, on wide screens

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this template :

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/eNe4v

The problem is that i would like my sidebar to become small or to hide, by clicking on a button, on a 22 " pc screen.

I've tried a few things with no success .

I'm using AngularJS, but maybe there should be a solution with Jquery ?

When the bar is hidden, the screen has to become larger, like in this template :

https://github.com/rdash/rdash-angular

but i can't use this one, because i don't use Gulp.

Thank you if you should have any idea , have a nice day.

When I'm hiding the SIDEBAR DIV with JQUERY, I only have this, a blank space, instead, but others div aren't resized automtically to fit all of the wide screen  :
[image]

Comment: give id to div of sidebar, and on button click call a function that will hide the div by id example: `$( "#id" ).hide();`

Comment: Thank you, i've tried but the screen doesn't resize all bootstrap elements, there is a blank space instead of the sidebar.

Comment: In that case you have to remove `col` class from that id and add `col-something-12` to the div you want to expand.

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this with a simple JS function

Here is an [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6f2dqd0g/1/)

```
$('#button').click(function () {
        $("#myDiv").animate({width:'toggle'},300); //300 is the speed (in ms)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of what i mentioned in comment. On click of button, the jquery will removing the class of column from sidebar, and then hide sidebar, and removing the class from content i.e. main information and give the class with 12 columns to it.

here is an [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/shyam004/DTcHh/34196/)

**html**

```
 <div class="container">
<div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-3">sidebar content</div>
<div id="content" class="col-sm-9"> <button type="button" onclick="myfunction()">hide the sidebar </button> </div> 
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
function myfunction(){
$("#sidebar").removeClass("col-sm-3");
$("#sidebar").hide();
$("#content").removeClass("col-sm-9");
$("#content").addClass("col-sm-12");
}
```